# How to find robot TCP in image with CalibrateHandEye

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, robotics

I'm currently developing a programm for a robot with a camera attached to the end affector.
The goal is to calculate where the robots TCP appears in the camera frame. I'm using opencv in c++.
The robot is a UR5 from Universal Robots.

My plan:

1. collect multiple (8) data-sets:

- robot pose (XYZ in meters, directly from the robot controller)
- robot rotation (rx ry rz in radians, directly from the robot controller)
- take a picture of calibration pattern for each step

2. run calibrateCamera over the set of pictures to get tvec and rvec for every step
3. run calibrateHandEye

- for t_gripper2base i use the robot pose
- for R_gripper2base i use the robot rotation
- for t_target2cam i use tvec from calibrateCamera
- for R_target2cam i use rvec from calibrateCamera

I seem to get correct values (I measured the distance from cam to TCP and the t_cam2gripper seems to be correct.

```
Translation vector target to cam: 
[-0.0001052803107026547;
 -0.0780872727019615;
 -0.1243323507069755]

Rotation matrix target to cam: 
[0.9999922523048892, 0.002655868335207422, -0.002905459271957709;
 -0.001229768871633805, 0.9119334002787367, 0.4103363999508009;
 0.003739384804660116, -0.4103296477461107, 0.9119296010009958]
```

The formula to transform the point from TCP coordinates to the image should look like this:

- (u,v,w) = C * T * (X,Y,Z,1)
  But after the division by w my values are still way off (should be around (600,600)

```
Actual image position vector homogenized: 
[1778.542462313536;
 -1626.72483032188;
 1]
```

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Mat defaultCameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3, 3));
    Mat defaultDistortion = (Mat_<double>(1, 5));
    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 0) = 1739.3749;   // default values from previous intrinsic camera calibration
    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 1) = 0;
    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(0, 2) = 639.5;

    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 0) = 0;
    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 1) = 1739.3749;
    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(1, 2) = 479.5;

    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(2, 0) = 0;
    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(2, 1) = 0;
    defaultCameraMatrix.at<double>(2, 2) = 1;

    defaultDistortion.at<double>(0, 0) = -0.165909;
    defaultDistortion.at<double>(0, 1) = 0.303675;
    defaultDistortion.at<double>(0, 2) = 0.0;
    defaultDistortion.at<double>(0, 3) = 0.0;
    defaultDistortion.at<double>(0, 4) = 0.0;

    vector<Mat> R_gripper2base, t_gripper2base, R_target2cam, t_target2cam;
    Mat actualRobotPos1 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotPos2 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotPos3 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotPos4 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotPos5 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotPos6 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotPos7 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotPos8 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1));

    actualRobotPos1.at<double>(0,0) = -0.193139;
    actualRobotPos1.at<double>(1,0) = 0.463823;
    actualRobotPos1.at<double>(2,0) = -0.025;
    t_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotPos1);

    actualRobotPos2.at<double>(0,0) = -0.193139;
    actualRobotPos2.at<double>(1,0) = 0.463823;
    actualRobotPos2.at<double>(2,0) = -0.025;
    t_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotPos2);

    actualRobotPos3.at<double>(0,0) = -0.21273;
    actualRobotPos3.at<double>(1,0) = 0.4426;
    actualRobotPos3.at<double>(2,0) = -0.0288;
    t_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotPos3);

    actualRobotPos4.at<double>(0,0) = -0.17213;
    actualRobotPos4.at<double>(1,0) = 0.4103;
    actualRobotPos4.at<double>(2,0) = 0.014;
    t_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotPos4);

    actualRobotPos5.at<double>(0,0) = -0.13724;
    actualRobotPos5.at<double>(1,0) = 0.45;
    actualRobotPos5.at<double>(2,0) = 0.02978;
    t_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotPos5);

    actualRobotPos6.at<double>(0,0) = -0.1655;
    actualRobotPos6.at<double>(1,0) = 0.478;
    actualRobotPos6.at<double>(2,0) = -0.0211;
    t_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotPos6);

    actualRobotPos7.at<double>(0,0) = -0.17018;
    actualRobotPos7.at<double>(1,0) = 0.46458;
    actualRobotPos7.at<double>(2,0) = -0.03761;
    t_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotPos7);

    actualRobotPos8.at<double>(0,0) = -0.193139;
    actualRobotPos8.at<double>(1,0) = 0.463823;
    actualRobotPos8.at<double>(2,0) = 0.025;
    t_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotPos8);

    Mat actualRobotRotVec1 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotRotVec2 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotRotVec3 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotRotVec4 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotRotVec5 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotRotVec6 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotRotVec7 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1)),
            actualRobotRotVec8 = (Mat_<double>(3, 1));

    actualRobotRotVec1.at<double>(0,0) = -3.14159;
    actualRobotRotVec1.at<double>(1,0) = 0.00;
    actualRobotRotVec1.at<double>(2,0) = 0.00719124;
    R_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotRotVec1);

    actualRobotRotVec2.at<double>(0,0) = -2.06;
    actualRobotRotVec2.at<double>(1,0) = -2.36;
    actualRobotRotVec2.at<double>(2,0) = 0.03;
    R_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotRotVec2);

    actualRobotRotVec3.at<double>(0,0) = 2.39;
    actualRobotRotVec3.at<double>(1,0) = 1.86;
    actualRobotRotVec3.at<double>(2,0) = 0.49;
    R_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotRotVec3);

    actualRobotRotVec4.at<double>(0,0) = -2.66;
    actualRobotRotVec4.at<double>(1,0) = 0.08;
    actualRobotRotVec4.at<double>(2,0) = 0.09;
    R_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotRotVec4);

    actualRobotRotVec5.at<double>(0,0) = -2.84;
    actualRobotRotVec5.at<double>(1,0) = 0.19;
    actualRobotRotVec5.at<double>(2,0) = 0.69;
    R_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotRotVec5);

    actualRobotRotVec6.at<double>(0,0) = 2.1;
    actualRobotRotVec6.at<double>(1,0) = -2.34;
    actualRobotRotVec6.at<double>(2,0) = -0.02;
    R_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotRotVec6);

    actualRobotRotVec7.at<double>(0,0) = 1.66;
    actualRobotRotVec7.at<double>(1,0) = -2.53;
    actualRobotRotVec7.at<double>(2,0) = -0.23;
    R_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotRotVec7);

    actualRobotRotVec8.at<double>(0,0) = -3.14159;
    actualRobotRotVec8.at<double>(1,0) = 0.00;
    actualRobotRotVec8.at<double>(2,0) = 0.00719124;
    R_gripper2base.push_back(actualRobotRotVec8);

    //    for(int i = 0; i < t_gripper2base.size(); i++)
    //    {
    //        cout << t_gripper2base[i] << endl << endl;
    //    }

    //    for(int i = 0; i < R_gripper2base.size(); i++)
    //    {
    //        cout << R_gripper2base[i] << endl << endl;
    //    }

    vector<String> fileNames;
    glob("PATH*.png", fileNames, false); // directory of images
    vector<vector<Point2f>> corners(fileNames.size());
    Mat chessboardImg, chessboardImgGray;

    vector<Point3f> objp;
    vector<vector<Point3f>> worldCoordinates;
    int checkerBoard[2] = {9,6};
    double fieldSize = 0.008;

    Mat cameraMatrixHandEye, distortionHandEye;
    vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;

    for(int i = 1; i < checkerBoard[1]; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < checkerBoard[0]; j++){
            objp.push_back(Point3f(j*fieldSize, i*fieldSize, 0));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        chessboardImg = imread(fileNames[i]);
        cvtColor(chessboardImg, chessboardImgGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        bool patternFound = findChessboardCorners(chessboardImgGray, Size(8,5), corners[i],  CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

        if(patternFound)
        {
            cornerSubPix(chessboardImgGray, corners[i],Size(11,11), Size(-1,-1), TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(chessboardImg, Size(8,5), corners[i], patternFound);
            worldCoordinates.push_back(objp);
        }
        //***** Check loaded images and detected chessboard *****
        //imshow("source", chessboardImgGray);
        //imshow("chess", chessboardImg);
        //waitKey(0);
        //*******************************************************
    }
    float reprojectionError = calibrateCamera(worldCoordinates, corners, Size(1280,960), cameraMatrixHandEye, distortionHandEye, rvecs, tvecs, CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO + CALIB_FIX_K3 +
                                              CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT);

    //***** Check camera calibration results *****
    //cout << "Reprojection Error CHE: " << endl << reprojectionError << endl << endl;
    //cout << "Camera Matrix CHE: " << endl << cameraMatrixHandEye << endl << endl;
    //cout << "Distortion CHE: " << endl << distortionHandEye << endl << endl;
    //for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoses; i++)
    //{
    //    cout << "No. " << i+1 << " Target translation: " << endl << tvecs[i] << endl << endl;
    //    cout << "No. " << i+1 << " Target rotation: " << endl << rvecs[i] << endl << endl;
    //}
    //********************************************/

    for(int i = 0; i < rvecs.size(); i++)
    {
        t_target2cam.emplace_back(tvecs[i]);
        R_target2cam.emplace_back(rvecs[i]);
    }

    //    for(int i = 0; i < t_target2cam.size(); i++)
    //    {
    //        cout << t_target2cam[i] << endl << endl;
    //    }

    //    for(int i = 0; i < R_target2cam.size(); i++)
    //    {
    //        cout << R_target2cam[i] << endl << endl;
    //    }

    Mat R_cam2gripper;
    Mat t_cam2gripper = (Mat_<double>(3, 1));
    calibrateHandEye(R_gripper2base, t_gripper2base, R_target2cam, t_target2cam, R_cam2gripper, t_cam2gripper);

    cout << t_cam2gripper << endl << endl;
    cout << R_cam2gripper << endl << endl;

    Mat transformationMat4x4 = (Mat_<double>(4, 4));
    Mat transformationMatInv4x4 = (Mat_<double>(4, 4));
    Mat R_cam2gripperInv = (Mat_<double>(3, 3));
    Mat t_cam2gripperInv = (Mat_<double>(3, 1));

    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(0, 0) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(0, 0);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(0, 1) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(0, 1);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(0, 2) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(0, 2);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(0, 3) = t_cam2gripper.at<double>(0, 0);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(1, 0) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(1, 0);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(1, 1) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(1, 1);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(1, 2) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(1, 2);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(1, 3) = t_cam2gripper.at<double>(1, 0);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(2, 0) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(2, 0);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(2, 1) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(2, 1);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(2, 2) = R_cam2gripper.at<double>(2, 2);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(2, 3) = t_cam2gripper.at<double>(2, 0);
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(3, 0) = 0;
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(3, 1) = 0;
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(3, 2) = 0;
    transformationMat4x4.at<double>(3, 3) = 1;

    transformationMatInv4x4 = transformationMat4x4.inv();
    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(0,0) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(0,0);
    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(0,1) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(0,1);
    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(0,2) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(0,2);

    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(1,0) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(1,0);
    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(1,1) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(1,1);
    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(1,2) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(1,2);

    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(2,0) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(2,0);
    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(2,1) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(2,1);
    R_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(2,2) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(2,2);

    t_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(0,0) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(0,3);
    t_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(1,0) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(1,3);
    t_cam2gripperInv.at<double>(2,0) = transformationMatInv4x4.at<double>(2,3);

    cout << transformationMatInv4x4 << endl << endl;
    cout << t_cam2gripperInv << endl << endl;


    Point3f objectPoints1, objectPoints2;
    vector<Point3f> objectPoints;

    objectPoints1.x = 0;    //TCP in TCP-Coordinates
    objectPoints1.y = 0;
    objectPoints1.z = 0;
    objectPoints.push_back(objectPoints1);

    vector<Point2f> imagePoints;
    projectPoints(objectPoints, R_cam2gripperInv, t_cam2gripperInv, defaultCameraMatrix, defaultDistortion, imagePoints);
    cout << imagePoints[0] << endl << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use solvepnp to get rvec and tvec for each image separately and then you will have a list of rvecs and tvecs. list length equals no of images. To get a similar list of rvec and tvec for Gripper_to_base transformation, you need to derive the R and T matrices based on robot dynamics which take rotation angle as input. Then for each pose you need to input the rotation angle data to R,T matrices to get rvec and tvec for each pose and make list of same length. Then you input them to calibrateHandeye function.

Comment: Thank you, for your comment! I think that calibrateHandEye uses the solvePnP Function to calculate rvecs and tvecs. The output of calibrateHandEye (at least the translation) seems to be fine, so I think, that my problem is located somewhere else...

Comment: Thanks, May be then I have done it wrong. So did you input one rvec and tvec for all poses? 1 rvec (target to cam), 1 tvec (traget to cam), 1 rvec (gripper to base), 1 tvec (gripper to base) instead of a list of them 1 for each pose? Please post here if you found a solution. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is possible to do in both ways, solvePnP only, or calibrateCamera (which uses solvePnP internally). I collected 8 samples: 8 robot poses with translation and rotation, as well as 8 pictures (pictures matching the poses). calibrateHandEye seems to only take lists (vector of mat) as input.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!, I just tested using both ways (i.solvepnp, ii calibratecamera). Got the same results. Still having the issue with HandEye calibration results. Translation seems right but Rotation matrix doesn't make sense.

Comment: How do you check the rotation matrix?

Comment: if you know the rotation between the two coordinate systems, you can compare it with the angle obtained from rotation matrix. These references helped me understand about rotation matrix. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati/3554913 and http://blog.espol.edu.ec/matg1049/files/2019/08/Doc2019_coordenadas_robot.pdf

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue. Would you like to share your code?

Comment: When you obtain your Target to camera matrices, were your object points given in base coordinates? Is that the same base coordinates you use for TCP to base. I think my issue is somewhere around TCP to base matrices, but cant figure out.

Comment: I added the code to my question! Target to cam has nothing to do with base coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally resolve the problem.
The calibration was correct, but there were two mistakes in my approach:

- To find my TCP I used the TCP-Coordinates from the robot control. Instead I had to use (0,0,0), which is the TCP in the TCP-Coordinate-System.
- The second mistake was to use the transformation matrix built from R and t out of calibrateHandEye. Instead I had to use the inverse transformation matrix.